# Using a TreeNode as a User Setting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, settings

I'm trying to use a TreeNode (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode) as a user setting for one of my applications.

```
if(treeView.SelectedNode != null)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode = treeView.SelectedNode;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Then on Application Load I'm trying to use that Setting

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode != null)
    treeView.SelectedNode= Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode;
```

but no matter what I do, `Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode` is always null when I reload the application.

I've also tried just using an Object and casting to a TreeNode, but that doesn't work either.

I really don't want to use string Settings for this, and want to stick with TreeNode if possible, but a serialized TreeNode would work if there is no way to use a TreeNode. I'm just not too familiar with Serialization.

Comment: a) TreeNode actually is serializable but it doesn't come back in a restart. It does get stored while the app runs, though. I can't explain why that is so or how to workaround. color is not serializable but it works fine !? - b) do note that even if it came back it should still be a new copy of the node and your code should not select it in the tree, if that was actually what you meant. If you want to add it to the treeview along with labels and childnodes you will have to write code for that..!

Comment: So you do not, as you wrote, want to store a TreeNode itself, with all its chil nodes, tags etc.. but only a reliable way to select that node.. Quite misleading question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you could store `TreeNode` in settings, you cannot assign deserialized node to `SelectedNode` property of `TreeView`. `TreeNode` is reference type and since the instance which you load from setting is not the same instance which exists in the tree, the assignment doesn't make sense and will not work. It's already mentioned in point b in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308604/using-a-treenode-as-a-user-setting#comment93500445_53308604) by Taw.

To preserve selected node in settings, it's better to rely on a string property. You have at least two options:

1. Store `Name` property of the node in settings
2. Store `FullPath` property of the node in settings

**Option 1  - Name Property**

Each `TreeNode` has a `Name` property which can be used to find the node.

- Assign a unique key to nodes when creating them:

  ```
  treeView1.Nodes.Add("key", "text");
  ```
- When saving data, store `treeView1.SelectedNode.Name` in settings.
- To select the node based on the settings:

  ```
  treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find("some key", true).FirstOrDefault();
  ```

**Option 2  - FullPath Property**

Each `TreeNode` has a `FullPath` which gets the path from the root tree node to the current tree node.

> The path consists of the labels of all the tree nodes that must be
>   navigated to reach this tree node, starting at the root tree node. The
>   node labels are separated by the delimiter character specified in the
>   PathSeparator property of the TreeView control that contains this
>   node.

- When creating node, you don't need to do special settings. Every node has `FullPath`.
- When saving data, store `treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath` in settings.
- To select the node based on the settings:

  ```
  treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.FindByPath(@"path\to\the\node");
  ```

In above code, `FindByPath` is an extension method which you can create to find the ndoe by path:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class TreeViewExtensiona
{
    public static TreeNode FindByPath(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, string path)
    {
        TreeNode found = null;
        foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            if (n.FullPath == path)
                found = n;
            else
                found = FindByPath(n.Nodes, path);
            if (found != null)
                return found;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used Option 2 here. I feel FullPath is exactly what I wanted, and the FIndByPath extension is very simple.

Comment: plus1 for mindreading :-) The other answer is quite useful when one actually  wants to store a treenode.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the call to the `Save` method attempts to serialize the node in order to store it in the `User.config` file. If you inspect this file, you will find that the node is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="..." >
            <section name="SomeProject.Properties.Settings" type="..." allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <SomeProject.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SelectedTreeNode" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value /> <!-- The node was not serialized! -->
            </setting>
        </SomeProject.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

The reason is probably that the `Save` method is attempting the serialization using the `XmlSerializer` class, which does not respect the `ISerializable` interface, which is how serialization is implemented for the `TreeNode` class. It blows up internally at some point and it swallows the error, leaving an empty value instead.

What you can do to get around this is serialize the `TreeNode` object using a proper serialization method, which is a formatter. Formatters respect the `ISerializable` interface. You can then store the resulting `string` in the setting and later read it and materialize it into the node:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode))
{                
    Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode = SerializeNode(treeView.SelectedNode);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

On application load:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode != null)
    treeView.SelectedNode= DeserializeNode(Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedTreeNode);
```

The serialization functions:

```
public string SerializeNode(TreeNode node)
{
    var formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, node);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var serialized = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return serialized;
        }
    }
}

public TreeNode DeserializeNode(string nodeString)
{
    var formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(nodeString);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            var node = (TreeNode)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return node;
        }                
    }          
}
```

For this answer, I am using the `SoapFormatter` class. You will need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap`.

Comment: Great answer to he question as written. Pitty it is not what ghe actually meant but may come useful to folks mislead by the question tile etc.. I wish I could upvote more than once..