# I want to know the selected node index counted from top included the parent nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have used the TAG and TEXT, is there has any other way to keep track the selected node or the other properties to assign the value to node?

[image: TreeView-Selected Node]

Comment: Selected node is `SelectedNode`. It has `Name`, `FullPath` and `Tag`. What's your requirement?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want to know its property other than name, text. In fact, i want to know its position from the beginning.

Comment: You can find it, but maybe if you let us know what's the usage of such information, we can suggest a better option. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53308604/3110834).

Comment: The selected node index is needed to update the database if user check/uncheck the checkbox

Comment: If you want to add additional properties to a TreeNode create a class that inherits the treeNode and then add additional properties.  Trying to keep track of the index is error prone : public class MyTreeNode : TreeNode{ }

Comment: Just store the `Key` field of the database `Record` in `Name` or `Tag` property and use it to find to which record is the node related.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to flatten the tree structure, then find the node index in the list.

For example, create the following Extension method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class TreeNodeCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AsEnumerable(this TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode c1 in nodes)
        {
            yield return c1;
            foreach (TreeNode c2 in AsEnumerable(c1.Nodes))
                yield return c2;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
//using System.Linq;
var index = treeView1.Nodes.AsEnumerable().ToList().IndexOf(treeView1.SelectedNode);
```

**Note**

Index of the node is not a reliable information to find the node and I just shared the answer for learning purpose. If you want to map a node to a database record, you just need to store the key field of the database record in `Name` or `Tag` property and use it to find to which record is the node related.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.